# How to work with glDrawArrays and glVertexPointer?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, opengl-compat

I need to rework my programme from `glVertex` to `glDrawArrays` and I am trying to sort out with this functions. Can you explain why this code doesn't work and how to change it, so it draws 2 triangles?

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.gl as pgl


win = pyglet.window.Window(1300, 1000, resizable=True)



@win.event
def on_draw():

    array = [100, 100, 0,
             500, 300, 0,
             900, 100, 0,
             100, 300, 0,
             500, 500, 0,
             900, 300, 0]


    pgl.glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0)
    pgl.glEnableClientState(pgl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    pgl.glVertexPointer(3, pgl.GL_FLOAT, 18, (pgl.GLubyte * len(array))(*array))

    pgl.glDrawArrays(pgl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0,18)
    pgl.glDisableClientState(pgl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)



pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the data in the buffer has to correspond to the type which is specified when the array of vertex data is defined by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml).
Since the set type is `GL_FLOAT`, the array data has to be of type `GLfloat`:

```py
data = (pgl.GLfloat * len(array))(*array)
```

The 3rd parameter (`stride`) of [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) (and similar functions) specifies the byte offset between consecutive attributes.
Since each vertex consists of 3 components (x, y, z) and the size of one component is the  size of `GLfloat`, the `stride` has to be 3*4 = 12.
Since the buffer is tightly packed, `stride` can be set 0, too. This is special case provided by `glVertexPointer` (and similar functions). If the `stride` is set 0, it is automatically calculated by the `size` and `type` parameter.

```py
pgl.glVertexPointer(3, pgl.GL_FLOAT, 0, data)
```

Final code:

[image]

```py
import pyglet
import pyglet.gl as pgl

win = pyglet.window.Window(1300, 1000, resizable=True)

@win.event
def on_draw():

    array = [100, 100, 0,
             500, 300, 0,
             900, 100, 0,
             100, 300, 0,
             500, 500, 0,
             900, 300, 0]


    pgl.glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0)
    pgl.glEnableClientState(pgl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    data = (pgl.GLfloat * len(array))(*array)
    pgl.glVertexPointer(3, pgl.GL_FLOAT, 0, data)

    pgl.glDrawArrays(pgl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18)
    pgl.glDisableClientState(pgl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: And if I want for example to put in array coordinates of vertex (x,y,z), coordinates of normal (x1,y1,z1) and coordinates of texture (x2,y2,z2) the parameter stride would be 9?

Comment: @PopeyeTheSailor No if the type is `GLfloat`, the stride is 9*4 = 36. For the normal vector you've to add an offset to the data pointer of 3*4 = 12 and to the texture coordinates an offset of 6*4=24.